# How to customize preferences screen theme to look like that?

Tags: android, themes, preferences, customization

Ok, I have a Preferences activity set with an XML layout.
Here I have a couple of Preferences that open some dialogs. On these preferences I want to have an arrow on the right of them like in the screenshot. How I do this, is something related to the theme ?
First screenshot is how I want to look, second is what I have now.

http://img545.imageshack.us/i/screenshot1zlk.png/

http://img405.imageshack.us/i/tsc3.png/

Comment: It's something in the theme that can vary between device manufacturers. I have had devices that show this arrow at the side and others which do not, even with the same app.

Comment: It might be but on my device both of these variations run, I have one program with the arrow, and another without it.

Comment: You can subclass PreferenceScreen (and related) and do anything you want, but I would argue that you should not do that. The idea with preferences is that they look uniform across different apps. And, just because some apps are already doing it doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: both photos have been deleted, please could you add them inline?

Answer (score 21):

In your preference activity you can set whatever you want to appear in each preferences "widget_layout" (the area to right of the title/summary) like so:

Via XML:

```
<Preference
android:key="Settings_CustomBG"
android:title="@string/Custom_BG"
android:widgetLayout="@layout/ic_custom"
/>
```

OR programatically:

```
   Preference BGColor = findPreference("Setting_BG_Color"); 
   BGColor.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.ic_custom);
```

Where ic_custom.xml (in /layout) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_custom"
/>
```

and ic_custom is just an image file in the resources folder(s). In my case this looks like the following:

[image: example of custom widget layout in an android preference]

Comment: What about on the left side? It it possible to do this way?

Comment: @NunoGonçalves that's actually very easy. just use android:icon.

        <Preference
            android:icon="@drawable/facebook_icon"
            android:key="facebook_main"
            android:summary="@string/main_facebook_text"
            android:title="@string/main_facebook_title" />

Comment: is also possible to access to the ImageView at runtime?

Comment: Yes, give the ImageView an id in the XML file and override Preference.onBindView(). There you can get the ImageView with findViewById().

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of `Preference`. A generic "Preference" type will appear blank, a `CheckBoxPreference` naturally has a `CheckBox`, and for what you're interested in, the  `DialogPreference` (and child) have the arrow:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html